# goosh (run on web server)

Tags: javascript

I downloaded [goosh](http://code.google.com/p/goosh/) but do not understood how to run it on web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in order to run it you need to just create a web page that calls the goosh javascript libraries. There doesn't appear to be any documentation about how to set it up locally but you could probably just copy the page at [Goosh.org](http://www.goosh.org) and start from there.